# jenkins adds @ (at sign) to workspace name after job killed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use jenkins pipelined project to build my OpenEmbedded based project. The node of my declarative pipeline contains

```
customWorkspace "/data/jenkins/oe/"
```

Jenkins actually builds one directory deeper, in

```
/data/jenkins/oe/project-name/
```

which is not a problem. But after I killed one job during development, jenkins now adds the at sign to path, such as

```
/data/jenkins/oe/project-name@2/
```

and this kills OE.

The `...@2` directory is restored even if I delete everything from `/data/jenkins/oe/`. I aslo tried enabling concurrent builds, based on [this bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21622), but none of these works.

What causes this behavior and how to avoid it? Either to disable the at sign usage, or to disable the subdirectory usage?

Comment: Any update on it ? I think I have the same problem..

Comment: @Thomas I don't have any clean solution. I detect this workspace early in pipeline by a special step (that checks if workspace path contains '@'). And when it happens, I manually shutdown jenkins, delete the directory and then start jenkins again.

Comment: Ok thanks ! If you use docker in your pipeline, maybe set the option `reuseNode` to `true` in docker part.

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same issue with concurrent builds.
Our solution is to use a custom workspace folder that doesn't contain nasty characters.

Here is the snippet from the `Jenkinsfile`:

```
// Custom workplace without nasty characters and prevent same name (master is master without nasty chars)
buildFolder = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(BRANCH_NAME, "UTF-8");
buildFolder = buildFolder + '_custom'
buildFolder = buildFolder.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "_");

//The actual pipeline
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'my pipeline'
            customWorkspace "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_pipeline/${buildFolder}"
        }
    }
    // remaining steps
...
}
```

In windows the path for the custom workspace is

```
customWorkspace "W:\\workdir\\my_pipeline\\${buildFolder}"
```

So it replaces every non alphanumeric character to `_` (underscore) and adds and extra `_custom` postfix at the end of the folder to prevent name clash.